# How to convert in pascal string to double?

Tags: pascal

How can i convert pascal string to double?

Answer (score 1):

Like this:

```
Val(YourString, YourDouble, ErrorCode);
```

ErrorCode (which is Integer) is needed to know if the conversion was successful.

Hope it helps :)

Comment: Did you understand my example?

Comment: Actually, in Turbo Pascal it is a word, not an integer :-)

Comment: @Marco, hmmm... Turbo Pascal - I taught it for like 12 years since 1990 :)

Actually, you can use either Word or Integer. And for those of you who loved TP, there's FreePascal now, and yes, it's open source.

Comment: itsols: in FPC it is overloaded. And yes I do know FPC http://www.freepascal.org/aboutus.var (scroll down to end) :-)